# Is there a one-time physical damage policy for cracked ipad2 a week after warrenty ends?

Tags: ipad, warranty, repair

My 1 year warranty has just ended within the last week and my daughter dropped my iPad 2 which has resulted in a cracked screen.

Is there a one-time physical damage replacement policy in Washington state, as there is in others?

Comment: What warranty are you referring to? AppleCare or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on consumer law but I am familiar with [Apple's warranty agreement in the US](http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/ipadwarranty.html).

AppleCare plus would cover physical damage by extending the normal one year manufacturer's warranty both in time to two years and in scope to actually cover physical damage.

The normal consumer warranty runs one year from purchase and does not cover accidental damage such as a drop. That being said, you could visit a store (or call AppleCare on the phone) and ask them if it could be covered, but I wouldn't expect coverage due to a drop one week from purchase or one week past one year under the normal manufacturer warranty. Be nice if you ask, they could say yes or they could say no but at least you tried.

You also could get a quote to repair and decide what makes the most sense for a repair / sell / replace decision on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Also try just taking it into an Apple Store and ask them.  Even if it just out of warranty, if you ask nice enough, they could still cover it.

Comment: My experience is that things that should be covered under the warranty might get a brief grace period depending on the situation, but not so much on something that the warranty wouldn't even cover on day two let alone on day 365+2.